# Custom calendar // android-times-square // How to get mont and year from CalendarCellDecorator in decorate method

Tags: android, android-calendar

I try to change background for dates from my array. Dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format, but i receive 119 as month and 119 as year using date.getMonth() and date.getYear(). Below my solution but it looks too precarious

```
public class MonthDecorator implements CalendarCellDecorator {
String mTest;

public MonthDecorator(String bookingDates) {
    mTest = bookingDates;
}

public void decorate(CalendarCellView calendarCellView, Date date) {
    String mYear = Integer.toString(date.getYear() - 100 + 2000);
    String mMonth = "0" + String.valueOf(date.getMonth() + 1);
    String mDay = String.valueOf(date.getDate());
    Log.i("MonthDecorator", "Дата " + date);
    Log.i("MonthDecorator", "ГОД " + mYear);
    Log.i("MonthDecorator", "Месяц " + mYear);
    Log.i("MonthDecorator", "День " + mDay);


    String dateFromCal = new StringBuilder().append(mYear)
            .append("-").append(mMonth).append("-").append(mDay)
            .toString();
    JSONObject bookingDatesObj = null;
    try {
        bookingDatesObj = new JSONObject(mTest);
        JSONArray bookingDatesArr = bookingDatesObj.getJSONArray("booking_dates");
        String dateFromArray = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < bookingDatesArr.length(); i++)
            dateFromArray = String.valueOf(bookingDatesArr.getString(i));
            Log.i("MonthDecorator", "Собранная дата календаря " + dateFromCal);
            Log.i("MonthDecorator", "Дата из массива " + dateFromArray);
            if (dateFromCal == dateFromArray) {
                calendarCellView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(243, 135, 76));
            }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Any help apreciated.

Comment: What do you want to basically?Why are you subtracting 100 and adding 2000 to a date object?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code carefully i guess you are trying to compare a date object to another date you receive from a source and yes your solution seems to be precarious.What you need to do is use `SimpleDateFormat` and parse the source date to a date object
rather than converting it to a string ,then compare with the other date object you are sending to the method.

Try the following code to fit into your use case:

```
String dateFromServer = "2019-01-13";

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            Date dateToCompare = dateFormat.parse(dateFromServer);
            Date todaysDate = new Date();
            if (todaysDate.compareTo(dateToCompare) == 0){
                //TODO:do your work here
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: @ManuGarg I saw and was not helpfull in my case as soon as I need to change background color for dates from array